# Can we execute two query from single model method in codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am having a controller which calls the model method like this:
Now in my first query I want to fetch values below 100 and in another I want to fetch above 100 ! Also I want to send them to my controller in two different array So Please guide me here.

The $firstarray contains all login data but now I want another array in which I have entry which are below 100.

```
 public function index()
    {

  $firstarray = $this->data['attendances'] = $this->attendance_m->join_data();

    $this->data['attendance_dropdown'] = $this->attendance_m->get_emp_list();
    $this->data['subview'] = 'admin/attendance/index';
    $this->load->view('admin/_layout_main', $this->data);
    }
```

And My Model Contains this method:

```
public function join_data()
    {


      $filter_date = $this->input->post('date_data');

      $date = new DateTime($filter_date);

      $new_date = $date->format('Y-m-d');

      $name = $this->input->post('attendance-list');

      $this->db->select('*');

      $this->db->from('daily_data2');

      $this->db->where('users.emp_id',$name);

      $this->db->where('entry >','100');

      $this->db->where('date(date_data)',$new_date);

      $this->db->order_by("date_data","ASC");

      $this->db->join('users', 'users.emp_id = daily_data2.emp_id','inner');

      $query = $this->db->get();

      $res   = $query->result();        
      echo $this->db->last_query();
      return $res;



      $this->db->select('*');

      $this->db->from('daily_data2');

      $this->db->where('users.emp_id',$name);

      $this->db->where('entry <=','100');

      $this->db->where('date(date_data)',$new_date);

      $this->db->order_by("date_data","ASC");

      $this->db->join('users', 'users.emp_id = daily_data2.emp_id','inner');

      $query2 = $this->db->get();

      $rese  = $query2->result();        
      echo $this->db->last_query();
      return $rese;

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do it, you needt to set to array the first 100 entry data and second 100 entry data then after that you may return it. See my codes:

```
public function join_data()
{
  $filter_date = $this->input->post('date_data');
  $date = new DateTime($filter_date);
  $new_date = $date->format('Y-m-d');
  $name = $this->input->post('attendance-list');
  $this->db->select('*');
  $this->db->from('daily_data2');
  $this->db->where('users.emp_id',$name);
  //      $this->db->where('entry >','100');
  $this->db->where('date(date_data)',$new_date);
  $this->db->order_by("date_data","ASC");
  $this->db->join('users', 'users.emp_id = daily_data2.emp_id','inner');
  $query = $this->db->get('',100,100); //Return data > 100
  $res_1  = $query->result();        

  $this->db->select('*');
  $this->db->from('daily_data2');
  $this->db->where('users.emp_id',$name);
  //      $this->db->where('entry <=','100');
  $this->db->where('date(date_data)',$new_date);
  $this->db->order_by("date_data","ASC");
  $this->db->join('users', 'users.emp_id = daily_data2.emp_id','inner');
  $query2 = $this->db->get('',100,0); //Return data <= 100
  $res_2  = $query2->result();        

  $returned_data = [
      'data_after_100' => $res_1,
      'data_below_100' => $res_2
  ];

  return $returned_data;
}
```